# How to calculate progression ratio of a set of numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, ratio

English is not my native language, so I will try to explain my problem.
I am doing web design and I am trying to use math to calculate the width of an element within different screen resolutions.
I found out that on resolution 1200, the element should have a width of 150. On resolution 991, the element should have a width of 78.
So the two sets are (991,1200) and (78,150).

```
991 -> 78
1200 -> 150
```

In CSS there is a unit (vw) which is equal to the current resolution. 
So for example if the user is on 1100 resolution, 100vw is equal to 1100. I will be using this unit to automate calculation for different resolutions and it will be incredibly useful if there is a formula for calculating the ratio between the two sets of numbers. My question is how to find the ratio on any current resolution? Also, is this called geometric progression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're looking for an arithmetic progression (not geometric).

The formula is: $78+(R-991)\frac{72}{209}$ where $R$ is the screen resolution.

**Method:**

For two "sets" (as you call them) $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$, you can easily find the formula like this:

$$b+(R-a)\frac{d-b}{c-a}.$$

Comment: This is exactly it! Can you provide me a formula with parameters instead of values

Comment: Check my answer for your question. :)

Comment: Thank you very much! What is the correct term for this problem. I don't know how to express it partly because of language barrier and partly because of math incompetence. However, I would like to learn the correct terms.

Comment: If you want to use more "mathematical" terms, you could say you're looking for an arithmetic progression $u_n$ such $u_{991}=78$ and $u_{1200}=150$.

Comment: Also use this https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference to use MathJax on your posts. And, by the way, welcome!